# Kohana + Safari + Resource tracking causes my session keys to reset

Tags: session, cookies, safari, kohana, php

I have a number of sites using Kohana's session handler set to use database sessions. Everything works fine until I turn on Resource Tracking in Safari's Web Inspector. After enabling resource tracking, the page refreshes (normal), but then if I refresh the page twice I get logged out. From what I can tell, the session id/key changes therefore it has no session. Upon watching the storage/cookies area, I can see the session id cookie change immediately.

I haven't been able to reproduce similar behaviour in any other browser, including Chrome (Webkit).

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be fixed in Safari 5.1, so in other words, no longer an issue. Still love to know why it was happening (in case there's another issue), but for now it's resolved.